# OpenGL: efficiently calculating transformation matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

So, I'm rendering a bunch a cubes; like, there will be thousands of cubes on the screen at once. The problem is that calculating transformations matrices every frame for each cube, as it turns out, isn't very efficient: 1,000 cubes renders at 54 fps and 10,000 cubes at 6 fps. I need to be able to change these transformation matrices because the player will be able to traverse them.

Here's my rendering code:

```
void Tester::render()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++)
        transforms[i] = Commons::PERSPECTIVE_MATRIX * translations[i];

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_transformationMatrixBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numInstances * sizeof(glm::mat4), &transforms[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(MVP_LOC + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (const void*)(sizeof(float) * i * 4));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(MVP_LOC + i);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(MVP_LOC + i, 1);
    }

    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, m_numIndexDataElements, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, numInstances);
}
```

Basically, my question is: how can I efficiently calculate transformation matrices for each cube instance?

Comment: Why do you think you need to tweak matrix calculation? Did you do profiling? If you will, you'll be probably surprised. Another thing: do you really need to change transforms of all of the 10k objects every single frame? Also, use VAOs.

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean by tweaking matrix calculation? You're probably right about not needing to change 10k transforms every frame, but I need to change at least 1k transforms. I'll implement VAOs.

Comment: By tweaking matrices I meant what you're asking in question: "efficiently calculate transformation matrices". Please [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) before any optimizations.

Comment: Without profiling it's an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

There is one operation that will be slow: the first for loop. instead just pass `Commons::PERSPECTIVE_MATRIX` as a uniform and just the translation part in the attribute.

Then in the vertex shader you will multiply them an then apply to the vertex.

If you need to have a per-instance rotation as well I would suggest passing a quaternion for that.